# Why are the only Angels left aligned with the 'good' gods?

Tags: magic, religion

I'm constructing a pantheon / theology for a fantasy world, and I'm a little stuck on a particular aspect.
Here's generally what I have so far:

There are three planes - one 'light', one 'dark', and the material plane.
There are 10 gods in the pantheon, each comprising a positive or negative aspect of an idea (gods for war and peace, light and dark, wealth and poverty, etc).
The gods are not inherently 'good' or 'evil', they just rule over separate aspects of the ideals. Aeyr, the God of Life, did not see things this way. He sought to rule over the Pantheon that life and light and peace might dominate the planes, with him as supreme ruler. Begdreus, the God of Death, sees Aeyr's powerplay as a threat to the balance that the Pantheon represents, and moves to oppose him. This kicks off a great war between the Gods. The 'dark' gods are close to victory (having the God of War on your side helps in this regard) when Aeyr, desparate to acheive his vision, performs an act that separates the planes from each other such that there is no longer any overlap between them, thus stranding the Pantheon on their separate planes, and stranding their Angels on the material plane. The Angels can be influenced by the gods that created them, but otherwise have no direct communication to the other planes.

Fast forward an indeterminate amount of time (1000 or more years). The only angels remaining are those bound to the 'light' gods... but I'm not really sure why at the moment.

I've considered a sort of battle between the light and dark angels following the separation of the planes, but that feels a bit clunky. Ultimately where I want to end up is with the 'light' gods able to influence their angels, but for the 'dark' gods to have no means whatsoever to interact with the material plane. I thought about having some sort of treaty between the two sides, but the mechanics of the world would then allow the 'dark' gods to have the same kind of limited communication with their angels that the 'light' ones have with theirs, and I want to avoid that.

If it helps, there is still inherent magic on the material plane from the time when it overlapped the 'light' and 'dark' planes, though its magnitude has waned somewhat in the time since.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the site! It seems to me like you could make basically anything up at this point. A battle, genocide, a (magical) plague, suicide pact by the dark angels, etc. I really don't see a way for one answer to be qualitatively superior to the another, which makes everything very ***opinion-based***. That is a close reason, here on WB. Do you think you could give us some more details?

Comment: This seems *opinion-based* to me too.  Is there some sort of rule system / answer grading criteria to go with this that would serve to distinguish the quality of answer you get?  Otherwise there could be many plausible reasons with no way to objectively determine which is best.

Comment: Hey Nightglow, welcome to Worldbuilding! it looks like you want help with developing a plot point or story development as distinct from developing a world or world mechanics.  As it stands your question isn't well suited to the scope of this site.  The following link may help clarify what is on-topic or off-topic: http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Green Yeah, that occurred to me as I was writing this up, but I figured I might as well lob it out there anyhow. I'll take another look at the on-topic rules and see if I can tease out an answerable question from my predicament. Feel free to close this question as off-topic.

Comment: @Nightglow, your world seems interesting.  I hope you can find something too :)

Answer (score 3):

Aeyr ripped the planes apart. It makes sense that he would guide the ripping in such a way that he can still communicate with his angels while others could not. Maybe his plane is closest to the material plane.
Perhaps initially even Aeyr could not reach his angels, but with his knowledge of the ripping he was able to devise a way to reach them more quickly than any others.

Angels with the guidance of their deity are more likely to be successful and survive. You could make it where most of the current angels actual belong to Aeyr. Since he only rarely lets the other gods through (if at all).

Comment: This question as written is likely getting closed as off-topic, but I appreciate the input and insight.

Comment: I feel anything that is not hard-science tagged tends to be opinion based, but I am only a small fry here.